intuition for Hausdorff maximal principle
I recently learned about the Hausdorf maximum principle which says that given a partially ordered set, there exists a maximal simply ordered subset, i,e,. a maximal subset in which each element is comparable to every other element. However the proof given is to select an arbitrary starting element, and then to go through the rest of the elements one by one, and add it to the set if it is comparable with every element in the set, and discard it otherwise. They claim the resulting set of elements will be a maximal simply ordered subset.
I'm sure I'm missing something very basic, but what if you had the set $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ where $a<b$ and $c<d<e$ but none of $c,d,e$ comparable with $a$ or $b$. Then wouldn't this proof give you $\{a,b\}$ as a maximal simply ordered subset, when in actuality $\{c,d,e\}$ is the correct maximally ordered subset.

Maximal by inclusion, of course, therefore both are maximal ordered subsets.

ahh I see makes sense

(totally ordered, I meant)
